# Android app force closes - setOnClickListener [simple app] [beginner]

Tags: java, android, class, onclicklistener, logcat

Program functions as normal on start up.  As soon as button is clicked, app force closes and the log cat (at bottom) is shown.

XML File - layout is fully functional

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.figurehowtodo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/produceText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myactualbutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ClickMe" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.figurehowtodo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button mybutton;
    TextView tvView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myactualbutton);
        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produceText1);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener());
    }

}
```

MyOwnOnClickListener.java

```
package com.example.figurehowtodo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyOwnOnClickListener extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    //int id;
    TextView id2;
    //TextView id3;

    /* MainActivity caller;
    public MyOwnOnClickListener() {
        addiTion();
        IGNORE THIS BIT
    } */

    public void onClick(View v) {
        addiTion(v);
    }

    public void addiTion(View v){
        //id = hello.getId();
        id2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produceText1);
        id2.setText("fgdsgdfhgdfh");
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at com.example.figurehowtodo.MyOwnOnClickListener.addiTion(MyOwnOnClickListener.java:29)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at com.example.figurehowtodo.MyOwnOnClickListener.onClick(MyOwnOnClickListener.java:22)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-27 20:56:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2132):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 20:56:31.720: W/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.example.figurehowtodo/.MainActivity
03-27 20:56:32.230: W/ActivityManager(61): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40698748 com.example.figurehowtodo/.MainActivity}
03-27 20:56:38.440: D/dalvikvm(299): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2544K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 55ms
03-27 20:56:43.380: W/ActivityManager(61): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40698748 com.example.figurehowtodo/.MainActivity}
03-27 20:56:43.480: D/dalvikvm(311): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 78ms
03-27 20:56:48.460: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_EXPLICIT freed 184K, 54% free 2764K/5959K, external 2202K/2671K, paused 56ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set you content view for your activity class `MyOwnOnClickListener`. So method `findViewById()` cannot find the view you are passing as argument.

I think the `MyOwnOnClickListener` class shouldn't be an `Activity` class, but just a listener. You can pass a reference to the `TextView` to the listener to use it.

Or you can implement the listener in your `MainActivity` class and suppress the `MyOwnOnClickListener` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button mybutton;
    TextView tvView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myactualbutton);
        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produceText1);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        addiTion(v);
    }

    public void addiTion(View v){
        tvView.setText("fgdsgdfhgdfh");
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you want to use a listener class, just keep your `MainActivity` as it is, change only the call to the `MyOwnOnClickListener` to pass the `tvView` reference, and change the `MyOwnOnClickListener` class like this:

```
public class MyOwnOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
TextView id2;

    // MainActivity caller;
    public MyOwnOnClickListener(TextView id2) {
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.produceText1:
            id2.setText("fgdsgdfhgdfh");
            break;
        // Other cases here...
        default:
            // Whatever you want to manage the situation...
        }
    }
}
```

It should work...

Comment: hi eternay, i kind of understand what your saying but you maybe write a bit of code to go with your explanation?, Thanks - ADDITION - i've just tried adding [setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);] under the public class area in [MyOwnOnClickListener.Class], its underlining it in red... do i have to create an [onCreate] method here?

Comment: your forgot to declare `id2`. In fact no need to declare another TextView since there is already the textView tvView set up before

Comment: Of course you can develop a listener into another class. Just create a constructor that receive a TextView as reference and call it in `setOnClickListener()` method passing the tvView reference. You have to change the code of your `MyOwnOnClickListener` class so that it uses the saved reference instead of calling the `findViewById()` method.

Comment: @donfuxx You are right, I'll correct my code now. I think you can suppress the `addition()` method and put the code directly in the `onClick()` method.

Comment: I am genuinely very sorry for asking again! :P, but could you please add code (while keeping your old code) to show how I would go about it (I'm fairly new to this stuff and haven't really got the hang of how to pass things down through methods ect) Thanks again!!

Comment: Well, basically the whole activity is written for you.. How about copy & paste the whole thing ;-) @user3470343

Comment: @donfuxx the addition() method was a test to see if I was able to call in multiple methods (for multiple buttons) depending on the button that was clicked. [using getId()]

Comment: I added code to show you how to manage in one listener clicks from various buttons. I Hope this code answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

replace your

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener());
```

by

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
         tvView.setText("fgdsgdfhgdfh");
    }   
});
```

which is called **anonymous class** in Java.

Setting listener this way, you declare *anonymous class* that *implements interface* `OnClickListener`, implement its *abstract method* `onClick` , *create an object* of this anonymous class and pass this object onto button's `setOnClickListener` method to make your button proceed clicks on it in a way you want.

Comment: Yes anonymous class could be done as well. But the findByView seems not necessary. He already has the field `tvView` looked up before and seems that is the one he wants to use. So could just do `tvView.setText("fgdsgdfhgdfh");`

Comment: @donfuxx sure, just trying to explain Java basics on fingers :) Know it is not easy to understand at the beginning.

Comment: thanks again guys :), but i was wanting to see if it was possible to run an [onclicklistner] into another class, probably might not be possible i guess.

Comment: Now this answer looks good :-) I guess you should have now learnt 3 possible ways of how to implement ClickListeners ;-) @user3470343

Comment: @user3470343 of course it is possible, if your `onClickListener` is in scope of visibility of `setOnClickListener`

Comment: @user3470343 your mistake is not about using custom classes to implement event listeners, but about trying to create another `Activity` in naive way with no care of its lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution with onClick attribute:**

Add this attribute to your Button in the xml:

```
android:onClick="buttonClicked"
```

and add this method to the MainActivity:

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
     tvView.setText("fgdsgdfhgdfh");
}
```

then also delete this line:

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener());
```

then get rid of the whole `MyOwnOnClickListener` Activity at all