# Error with custom OnClickListener class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener, logcat

The app force closes without even starting, see below for logcat info and (app works when 3 lines below are commented out)

- also says in the LogCat there is an issue with `NullPointerException` but I don't know where and how to solve it.

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.figurehowtodo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/produceText1"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myFirstButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ClickMe1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mySecondButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ClickMe2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myThirdButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ClickMe3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.figurehowtodo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button myFirstButton;
Button mySecondButton;
Button myThirdButton;
TextView tvView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    myFirstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myFirstButton);
    mySecondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mySecondButton);
    myThirdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myThirdButton);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produceText1);

    //if (tvView == null) { Log.w("", "TextView is null"); }
```

If I comment out the bottom three lines my app runs (but without any button functionality). I think the "new" might have something to do with it?

```
myFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener(tvView, "myFirstButton"));
mySecondButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener(tvView, "mySecondButton"));
myThirdButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener(tvView, "myThirdButton"));
```

MyOwnOnClickListner.java

```
package com.example.figurehowtodo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyOwnOnClickListener extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    //int id; //comment line out in order to make it work
    //TextView id3;

    /* 
    *
    *MainActivity caller;
    *public MyOwnOnClickListener() {
    *€  addiTion();
    *   IGNORE THIS BIT
    *} 
    *
    */

    TextView outputBoxId;
    String re_id_button_name;

    Button myFirstButton;
    Button mySecondButton;
    Button myThirdButton;
    TextView tvView3;

    public MyOwnOnClickListener(TextView id2, String id) {
        this.outputBoxId = id2;
        this.re_id_button_name = id;

        myFirstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myFirstButton);
        mySecondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mySecondButton);
        myThirdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myThirdButton);
    }

    public void onClick(View re_id_button_name) {
        //tvView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produceText1);
        outputBoxId.setText("it worked!!!");
    }

    /*
     * -------IGNORE---------
    if(re_id_button_name.equals(myFirstButton)){
        addiTion();
    }else{return;}

    public void addiTion(){
        //id = v.getId(); //comment line out in order to make it work

        outputBoxId.setText("YOU CLICKED THE FIRST BUTTON!");
    }
    -------IGNORE---------*/
}
```

LogCat:

```
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.figurehowtodo/com.example.figurehowtodo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.example.figurehowtodo.MyOwnOnClickListener.<init>(MyOwnOnClickListener.java:31)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.example.figurehowtodo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-28 21:56:24.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     ... 11 more
03-28 21:56:24.408: W/ActivityManager(62):   Force finishing activity com.example.figurehowtodo/.MainActivity
03-28 21:56:24.917: W/ActivityManager(62): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{407eda90 com.example.figurehowtodo/.MainActivity}
03-28 21:56:30.757: D/dalvikvm(233): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 55% free 2597K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 53ms
```

Comment: What happens if you put this back in: `//if (tvView == null) { Log.w("", "TextView is null"); }` . Is it null? Seems like it to me.

Comment: it doesn't make much of a difference, still force closes... is there a problem with the way my code is written?

Comment: No i mean if the logcat shows "TextView is null" before it crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android app force closes - setOnClickListener \[simple app\] \[beginner\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699188/android-app-force-closes-setonclicklistener-simple-app-beginner)

Comment: yep, get the same error "NullPointerException"

Comment: Yes, you will keep getting a `NPE` trying to call a method on a `null View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that your custom `OnClickListener` shouldn't `extends Activity` because it isn't an `Activity`. And such, it doesn't have the `layout` that holds the `id`s of the `View`s you are trying to inflate.

This is why it crashes because you get a `NPE` when trying to set the `listener` on those `View`s. You need to set the `listeners` on them in your actual `Activity` where you inflate the `layout` with `findViewById()`.

So, instead of having something like

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

you would have

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnOnClickListener());
```

**Edit**

Try this, use the `Context` from the `View` passed in to get the other `View`. I'm not positive this will work and I don't have time to test it at this moment but let's see.

```
public MyOwnOnClickListener(TextView id2, String id) {

    myFirstButton = (Button) id2.getContext().findViewById(R.id.myFirstButton);
}
```

Comment: perfect!, getting rid of the "extends activity" did the trick, one question though, in my 'MyOwnOnClickListener' class... if I wanted to get a view, how would i go about it? considering that the 'findViewById' no longer works due to 'extends activity' being absent.

Comment: You should be able to pass it in the constructor of that class

Comment: correct, but say I wanted to compare the id received through a parameter with another id which I don't want to pass through the prams (because it needs to be compared with more than one id...can't put all of them in prams).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Where would this other `id` come from to compare to? I think I will need a little more context to be of much help.

Comment: the other id's would be coming from the xml file/main activity, for example, say i wanted to compare id1 (came from prams + we are working in myownonclicklistner class), to id2 and id3 which where defined in the main activity as buttons. Is there a way i can retrieve the defined variables from main activity seen as though i cant use findViewById anymore?

Comment: Pass the `Activity context` to the constructor and use that to get the `Views`. I'm not a 100% but that should work.

Comment: if its not too much trouble could you write a bit of code to show what you mean?,Thanks :)

Comment: See my edit. That isn't what I was originally thinking but try that and if it doesn't work I will give another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple write

```
        Button myFirstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myFirstButton);
        myFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   

            }
        });
```

And also do same for other buttons.

Comment: The point of my app is to run the onClickListener into another class so I am able to later on call in various methods while still being able to navigate through my code, but thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: then its better if you pass button id with your parameter and use it in onClick method.